# Excel: Automate formatting from generated table

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a workflow to make the lives of my project managers easier.
I have financial profile of a client emailed to me automatically every month. The table lists the overall project information and then individual information for each phase of each project. the information is organized like below:

(Information starts at cell C7, headers are above that)

[Snapshot of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gV9w.png)

I want to create an environment where project managers can guess the percent completion of each phase for upcoming months to build a financial outlook plan for the client. Then the totals for each phase is summed and shown on the line for the overall project.

I wanted to automate the formatting process for this file. I could use some guidance or direction?

I have created a general format but do not know the best way to automate this.

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zrnb.png)

Edit:

I came up with some ugly work arounds. But am hoping to clean this up a bit. And I still need a solution for automating the process of bringing in data.

[Working Solution V1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKU1F.png)

I've done the following:
Column K is used to calculate each rows % completion.
Total Contract $$$ / JTD Billed $$$ (columns I/G) `=IF(G7>0,I7/G7,)`

Columns L, M, N are inputs for the project manager to estimate the completion percentage of each phase by month.

Columns O, P, Q are the outputs calculating the projected billable by month.

(delta % Complete) * Total Contract $$$ (Columns delta(K-N) * G)

However, because I wanted to sum the total billable amounts for each project in the project line, I needed a way to separate the project lines and phase lines.
So, I created Column R with a Boleen value (true/false) to determine if a line was a project overview or a phase. It compares the project number (column C) to the row above it. `=IF(C7=C6,TRUE)`

Then I needed a way to know how many rows (phases) below a project line belong to the project. I used column S to calculate with `=MATCH(1,--(R8:R100=FALSE),0)-1` which counts the number of columns to the next 'False' value.

I then used Columns T, U, V to sum the projected billable per phase per month for the project. `=IF(NOT($R7),SUM(O8:INDEX(O8:O1000,$S7,1)),0)`

*I don't like this formula because its messy. I can't figure out how to write O8:O (like O:O).*

And I showed the projected billables with this formula: `=IF($R7,IF(AND((L7-K7)*$G7>0,(L7-K7)<1),(L7-K7)*$G7,0),T7)`. If column R identifies a project row, columns O, P, Q show the sums of the phases. If column R identifies a phase row, columns O, P, Q calculate the billable amount.

Additionally, I used conditional formation using column R to visually distinguish between projects and phases.

Comment: With that working solution I am looking for a way to automatically update the data in the table when the email attachment is saved into the folder.

Comment: I decided to use the built-in Get & Transform Data method and use Power Automate to automatically get the email attachment and save it to a SharePoint folder. Power Automate will save the new file over the old file and Get & Transform Data automatically transform the data into a more usable format.

Now, the information is updated automatically.  I now need a method to shift the project manager's inputs as the data is updated monthly.